# UIButton highlighted when pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have two `UIButtons`. I was able to make them highlighted when pressed. :

```
-(IBAction) button1Pressed:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton1:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)highlightButton1:(UIButton *)a { 
    [a setHighlighted:YES];
}

-(IBAction) button2Pressed:(id)sender {

    [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton2:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)highlightButton2:(UIButton *)b { 
    [b setHighlighted:YES];
}
```

I wanted to unhighlight a button when the other button is highlighted.
But I can't make it work.

Comment: This would be super easy if both the buttons are connected to "`IBOutlets`".  Are they?  And if so, what are they named?

Comment: Yes they are named: mode 1 and mode 2 to sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have your buttons defined as:

```
IBOutlet NSButton * mode1;
IBOutlet NSButton * mode2;
```

then you can do:

```
- (void)highlightButton1:(UIButton *)a { 
    [mode1 setHighlighted:YES];
    [mode2 setHighlited:NO];
}

- (void)highlightButton2:(UIButton *)b { 
    [mode1 setHighlighted:NO];
    [mode2 setHighlited:YES];
}
```

parameters a & b are ignored in this particular case...